# Validate if register exists in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple insert like:

```
INSERT INTO Store.Cart VALUES (@UserId);
```

I want to validate if userId exists in table Store.Cart, don´t create it again. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Use a unique index or constraint:

```
alter table Store.Cart add constraint unq_cart_userId unique (userId);
```

The database will ensure that a user only appears once in the table.  Any attempt to add it again will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

it will be good too to always check for exists before insert/update

```
if not exists (select 1 from Store.Cart where UserId= @UserId)
begin
 INSERT INTO Store.Cart VALUES (@UserId);
end
```